# Bootstrap forms - Cannot make the label and input inline

Tags: html, css, forms, bootstrap-4

I am working on a personal project, and I need to make some changes to my current form but I cannot get it working so far.

I need the label and input to be inline. Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYsEA.jpg) how the form should look like.

And here is my current code:

```css
.personal_details {
    max-width: 503px;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 40px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="personal_details">
  <form class="personal_details">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="firstName">First name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFirstName" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="lastName">Last name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputLastName" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="phone_nummber">Account type</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="profile_type">
        <option value="Basic" selected>Freelancer</option>
        <option value="Company">Employer</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary mt-4 px-5" type="submit">EDIT</button>
  </form> <!-- Form ends here -->
</div>
```

Comment: Bootstrap has a sample of an inline form [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/#horizontal-form)

Comment: The .form-control class in Bootstrap has display:block and width:100%.

Comment: Try to add `d-flex` in class `form-group`